# linux application to control optical media

Tags: c++, linux, bash, signals, hardware

I want a graphical application for Linux that displays the contents of CD/DVD/blu-ray drives and allows play or eject, and I'd like the solution to be general, so that I can donate it to Linux Mint, that is any drive type and any number of drives. In my system I have three dvd drives and a blu-ray drive.

I'd like to write it in bash using the dialog functions inside a terminal window but I need to have the dialog displayed in perpitude therefore, I need an interrupt to signal when the drive is opened or closed - what signal could I trap? Also, how can I include logic to select a program to play the media depending on the media type.

Also, should I consider writing it in java, python, C++, or other language and if so how to get hardware information (such as the number and capability of drives, and the type and title of optical media in drive)?

Comment: It's clear what ejecting is, but what's "playing"? Opening the users favorite media player? [And where does the idea come from that the Mint team wants such a program donated? If there is a need for it, a skilled member can do it anytime, and the only reason the haven't yet is likely that they don't want such a thing. At least as bash program, there's not much use for that]

Comment: And what are "dialog functions inside the terminal window"?

Comment: @deviantfan I believe he refers to the `dialog` command that lets you show ncurses dialogs from within bash scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the side of "I want to donate this to Linux Mint", which I believe is a bit pretentious, there is a `eject` utility in Linux.

The source code of that can be found here:
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/sys-utils/eject.c

In that code, there is also code to sense if the drive is open, closed, has no disk, etc.

To do CD or DVD playback is a whole other kettle of fish. To write a audio-player is not entirely trivial (even in the simple case of a straightforward PCM encoding, obviously MP3 is a fair bit more complex again), and a video-player is a lot more than that.

To "select a program", you'd have to know what the available players may be called, and, if you want to be fancy, check which ones are actually installed. I'm not aware of any really clever way of achieving that, beyond having a list of players in your code (which needs to be updated). In fact, I know that is how the photo viewer geeqie works when you want to edit a shot: it has a list of "known editors", and it scans the PATH to find which ones are available.